# Check if the path matches with Active directory in Powershell

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-cli

i am trying to match the path of folder with AAD, if the value matches the AD group should be assigned to the folder. I am able to get the values, but its showing all the values of certain string.

Ex. 
The code that i wrote:

```
$a = Get-AzureADGroup

$b = $a.DisplayName
$c = project_aa
foreach($id in $gid){
  if ($b -match $c){
   ...
   }
}
```

The problem is: its takes all the vales in AD i.e.

My AD group starts with

1. AD_/project/_write
2. AD_/project_read

How can i say that, check if AD group has only 'project' and is not terminated with '/'. then assign permissions project_read to the folder.

Any suggestions?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to use foreach loop and also should do the validation inside the loop with conditional match. May be a regex match would be a better option here.

Comment: Hi @Ranadip, i already have a for loop to check the directories. i edited the question pls check.

Comment: that is for loop. m asking foreach loop. refer documents in google about it.

Comment: I already tried using foreach.. The answer is same..Apologies i wrote for here. I think regex might do the trick.

Comment: What are $id , $GID why the loop variables are not even used inside? what is the point of matching that inside. Form your logic properly. Reframe your question with proper code.